# Implicit and explicit definability over $\mathbb{R}$ of the exponential function

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

Let $L$ be a language, $M$ an $L$-structure, and $r$ an $n$-ary relation on $U_{M}$ (the domain of $M$).

Implicit definability:

> We say that $r$ is implicitly definable over $M$ if there is a sentence $\varphi$ in the language $L'=L\cup\{R\}$, where $R$ is a new $n$-ary predicate, such that for all $n$-ary relations $s$ on $U_{M}$ we have
> $$(M,s)\vDash\varphi\text{ iff } r=s.$$
> Where $(M,s)$ is the $L'$-structure with $R$ interpreted as $s$.

Explicit definability:

> We say that $r$ is explicitly definable over $M$ if there is an $L$-formula $\varphi$ with free variables $x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}$ such that
> $$r=\{(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}):M\vDash\varphi[x_{1}/a_{1},\ldots x_{n}/a_{n}]\}.$$

Let $\mathbb{R}:=(\mathbb{R},+,-,\cdot,0,1,<,=)$ be the ordered field of real numbers. How de we prove that the relation defined by the exponential function $e^{x}$ is implicitly definable but not explicitly definable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are too many details here to write an explicit solution in this answer box. But I'll give you a quick sketch (or, perhaps, an *implicit* solution?).

$e^x$ is implicitly definable: Use the fact that $e^x$ is the unique function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) = 1$, $f$ is differentiable everywhere, and $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. The work here is in expressing these concepts in a first-order way.

$e^x$ is not explicitly definable: Using the fact that the theory of the real field has quantifier elimination, show that every definable function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ grows asymptotically like a rational power of $x$, and hence is eventually dominated by $e^x$ as $x$ limits to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling that the explicit part would be more involved.  Do you know of references where I could read about the two main ingredients? Namely, that the ordered field of real numbers has QE, or perhaps more generally, that the theory or real-closed ordered fields has QE. And that definable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ grow asymptotically like rational powers of $x$. By definable function, do you mean that the graph of $f$ is definable via an $L$-formula having two free variables?

Comment: QE for real closed fields is a classic theorem due to Tarski and Siedenberg. There is a proof  in Marker's book *Model Theory: An Introduction*.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by definable function. Definable functions in the real ordered field are called "semialgebraic". [Here](https://gcomte.perso.math.cnrs.fr/M2/CosteIntroToSemialGeo.pdf) is a reference (Proposition 2.11) to a proof of the assertion the semialgebraic functions are bounded by polynomials asymptotically. I don't have a reference written by a logician in mind for this fact. It might be in *Tame Topology and o-minimal Structures* by van den Dries.